# Get file's links with google-drive-api python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I've worked with `Google Drive` `Api` some time and I can't find the way to get the link for file's view on Drive pragramatically.
There is `function` which creates folder and returns its id, however additionally I need to return a `link` for `view` only. 
Thank you!

```
def create_folder(folder_name='no_name', parent_id=''):
    data = {'name': folder_name,
            'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
            'parents': [parent_id],
            }
    new = DRIVE.files().create(body=data, fields='id').execute()
    return new.get('id')

folder = create_folder('some_name', 'some_parent_id')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, create folder and return a View link is possible by adding "webViewLink" to fields in method files().create(). The function will be the next:

```
def create_folder(parent_id, folder_name='no_name', ):
data = {'name': folder_name,
        'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        'parents': ['{0}'.format(parent_id)],
        }
new = DRIVE.files().create(body=data, fields='webViewLink, id').execute()
return new.get('webViewLink')
```